# Getting a variable from parse_str

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i am trying to read the responde from facebook graph. It send me the access_token but i cant seem to read it. This used to work but for some reason it stopped working today.

```
$token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?" . "client_id=" . $fb_app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($fb_return_url) . "&client_secret=" . $fb_app_secret . "&code=" . $code;

$response = file_get_contents($token_url);

$params = null;
parse_str($response, $params);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($params);
echo "</pre>";

$_SESSION['access_token'] = $params['access_token'];

$graph_url              = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" . $params['access_token'];
$facebook_user_info     = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url));
```

The above print_r() shows:

```
Array
(
    [{"access_token":"EAAXZBwzyN6xkBAD0szEptWK6tMJlH68HmmZA6SM2nZBZCoQgPIDAvNaL0Fv9z89nwJhkkRCNRJHvlS9rzn09EdUEbH9ZBVajZAVXlF0SJyoJhW3NvMZAyZB7MOMSbFEsQe4RKSTxiQIZCVxnMPYI3tSxsjxgVZBPZCrbAZD","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":5162746}] => 
)
```

but $params['access_token'] is always empty. How to properly get the access_token?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$response = file_get_contents($token_url);
```

here `$response` in an JSON object, you have to use `json_decode()` to convert it into an array like:

```
$resp = json_decode($response, true);
```

and use `$resp` like:

```
echo $resp['access_token'];
```

Comment: thanks, that works, i tried it but forgot the second parameter "true" for json_decode(), i wonder why it worked before... grr

Comment: If you don't pass true then it returns a Std Class object which can be accessed like `$resp->access_token`;